# Velocity: how to set txt content as variable

Tags: javascript, oauth, jira, velocity, confluence

I am implementing an add-on for Confluence. And during the oAuth, I have to read a private key from a file. For security reasons, they blocked fs for nodejs, and also I couldn't read a file with input stream or scanner in Java.
I am trying now to get the content to velocity and send it as a variable to my js file, in order to log in via oAuth.

## Velocity

```
#include("templates/file.txt")
```

If I use that, he prints out the content out. But how can I save the content as a variable?
I tried:

```
#set ($mypkey = #include("templates/file.txt"))
```

But it is now working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there.

```
#set ($mypkey = "#include('templates/file.txt')")
```

Comment: Oh so close =) Thank you very much!